# Implement a search and if statement in select statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, replace, mysql-workbench

I currently have the following:

```
if (SUBSTRING(data, 3), FIND_IN_SET ('"', data), REPLACE(data, '"', '')) AS column
```

But the result is always 0.

I want to use `select SUBSTRING(data, 3)` and if the substring contains comma then replace it with " ".

How can I do that?

Comment: you dont need to find , just directly use replace. it will replace if , is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(data, 3), ',', ' ') FROM your_table;
```